# Liquid float where next line elements snap to top

Tags: html, css, css-float

The black container has `{overflow:hidden;}`

The yellow blocks has the same order in code as the numbers, and has `{float:left;}`

This is what I would like to happen to the 5th element:

[image]

But this is what's happening right now:

[image]

What can I do to make the element that doesn't fit in line to snap to the element above it?

**Here's an [interactive example](http://jsfiddle.net/z4v8to91/).**

I'd like to avoid absolute positioning, because the elements are created dynamically. There could as well be potentially twice as many elements.

Comment: Are div generated dynamically or your can access the css?

Comment: The divs are generated dynamically, but I can access the css as well.

Comment: I am afraid this can't be done without that, as you'll need to clear off the `float`s but still `position`ing would be needed...!

Comment: @Numbers Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/z4v8to91/1/

Comment: @Sam1604 Thanx but as I wrote in the last lines, the content is dynamic so fixed/absolute positioning isn't a good solution..

Comment: You might want to consider using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). CSS floats are interpreted in such a way that a new row is always cleared of the previous one, preventing "snapping to top" behavior as you mentioned as the new row will be uniformly further from the previous row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you to use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for this kind of things, but in the meanwhile, here's how to solve it:

```
.container {overflow:hidden; background-color:#000; width: 360px; text-align: center;}
.block {float:left; height:50px; width:70px; background-color:yellow; margin:10px;}
.high {height:150px; float:right}

.container2 {overflow:hidden; background-color:#000; width: 98%; height:80vh; text-align: center;}
.container2 .block {float:left; height:20%; width:23%; background-color:yellow; margin:1%;}
.container2 .high {height:40%; float:right}
```

I have added a responsive example so you can see how it reacts. [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j9bw8hhp/) . This will work in your scenario, but I'm sure you'll notice the limitations

Comment: Masonry looks terrific! Thanx a bunch.